# How do you nest a select in an if?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, if-statement, firebird

I'm very new to Firebird, but I want to know how I can use a select statement as part of my conditional criteria.  I feel like I've been to the internet in back trying to find a way to do this, but haven't come up with much.  Below is my attempt at getting this to work.

```
SET TERM ^ ;
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_test (
IPADD Varchar(32),
HN Varchar(32),
NOTE Varchar(200) )
RETURNS ( update_count integer )
AS
BEGIN
IF((SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM ADDRESSES a
    WHERE a.ADDRESS_TYPE = 'Reserved'
      AND a.ALIVE = 'N'
      AND (a.HOST_NAME = '' OR a.HOST_NAME is NULL)
      AND (a.DNS_NAME = '' OR a.DNS_NAME is NULL)
      AND (a.SYSTEM_NAME = '' OR a.SYSTEM_NAME is NULL)) > 0)
THEN
  UPDATE 
    ADDRESSES a
  SET
    a.HOST_NAME = :HN,
    a.ADDRESS_TYPE = 'Assigned',
    a.NOTES = :NOTE
  WHERE
    a.SHORT_IP_ADDRESS = :IPADD;
  update_count = 1;
  SUSPEND;
ELSE
  update_count = 0;
  SUSPEND;
END^
SET TERM ; ^

GRANT EXECUTE
ON PROCEDURE sp_test TO  SYSDBA;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `COUNT` to check is there records to update is not the best way, use `EXISTS` instead, ie your `IF` would be

```
IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ADDRESSES a
    WHERE a.ADDRESS_TYPE = 'Reserved'
      AND a.ALIVE = 'N'
      AND (a.HOST_NAME = '' OR a.HOST_NAME is NULL)
      AND (a.DNS_NAME = '' OR a.DNS_NAME is NULL)
      AND (a.SYSTEM_NAME = '' OR a.SYSTEM_NAME is NULL)))
THEN
```

But there seems to be a problem with your return value, `update_count` - you return 1 if you execute the `UPDATE`, but the actual number of rows affected by the statement might be something else. I suggest you use `ROW_COUNT` context variable instead. So your procedure would be

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_test (
IPADD Varchar(32),
HN Varchar(32),
NOTE Varchar(200) )
RETURNS ( update_count integer )
AS
BEGIN
  IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ADDRESSES a
    WHERE (a.ADDRESS_TYPE = 'Reserved')
      AND (a.ALIVE = 'N')
      AND (a.HOST_NAME = '' OR a.HOST_NAME is NULL)
      AND (a.DNS_NAME = '' OR a.DNS_NAME is NULL)
      AND (a.SYSTEM_NAME = '' OR a.SYSTEM_NAME is NULL)))
  THEN BEGIN
     UPDATE ADDRESSES a SET
       a.HOST_NAME = :HN,
       a.ADDRESS_TYPE = 'Assigned',
       a.NOTES = :NOTE
     WHERE a.SHORT_IP_ADDRESS = :IPADD;
     update_count = ROW_COUNT;
  END ELSE update_count = 0;
  SUSPEND;
END^
```

Comment: Addition for further optimizing: 1) Table aliases are excessive here 2) You can use `CHAR_LENGTH(aField) > 0` instead of `aField IS NULL OR aField = ''`. It slightly clarifies the code.